# How is the value to create an order request being assigned?

Tags: trigger

I am not a developer and am new to Apex Triggers.

How is this piece of code assigning the value to the field Create Order request?

```
if(checkRecursive.runOnce()){
    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
        Boolean oldOrderRequest;
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            oldOrderRequest = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Create_Order_Request__c;
        }else if(Trigger.isInsert){
            oldOrderRequest = false;
        }

        if(opp.Create_Order_Request__c == true && opp.Create_Order_Request__c != oldOrderRequest){
            oppIds.add(opp.Id);
            WorkOrder newWorkOrder = new WorkOrder();
            newWorkOrder.Pricebook2Id = opp.Pricebook2Id;
            newWorkOrder.Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
            newWorkOrder.CurrencyIsoCode = opp.CurrencyIsoCode;
```

Comment: This code is getting hold of the current value most likely to see whether or not a database update is needed; so this is likely to be followed by `if (opp.Create_Order_Request__c != oldOrderRequest) {` that will then contain the assignment.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Your code is incomplete since there is no actual assignment of the Create Order Request field.  Please [edit] your post to include the relevant portions.

Comment: @keithC Thanks for your reply. This is what is confusing because this is following which is again I think verifying whether it is True or not but nowhwere it is assigning it as true. `if(opp.Create_Order_Request__c == true && opp.Create_Order_Request__c != oldOrderRequest){
                oppIds.add(opp.Id);
                WorkOrder newWorkOrder = new WorkOrder();
                newWorkOrder.Pricebook2Id = opp.Pricebook2Id;
                newWorkOrder.Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
                newWorkOrder.CurrencyIsoCode = opp.CurrencyIsoCode; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not assigning a value to Create_Order_Request__c. It is verifying if the contents of that field changed from false to true due to an update.

This is being done by checking the old value stored in the Trigger.oldMap, which contains the values of the records modified *before* the modification.

```
oldOrderRequest = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Create_Order_Request__c;
```

This is done only on update. So the value will only be true on update.

Then it compares the value with the actual value to check if it has changed.

```
if(opp.Create_Order_Request__c == true && opp.Create_Order_Request__c != oldOrderRequest){
```

But there is no *assignment* of the value to the field Create_Order_Request__c, but rather creating a new Boolean variable.

If the conditions are met (the field has changed on an update [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) operation) then the conditions inside the *if* are done.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Thanks a lot for the answer. This confirms my belief that this trigger is not assigning any value to it. However, it still confuses me on how the value to this varibale is being assigned. But thanks a lot!

Comment: If the field is visible on a Page layout then it can be modified that way. Otherwise as stated on the message it can be modified via other automations. 

Boolean fields only have 2 possible values True and false and therefore a default value is required and unlike other types of fields it can't have a null value. This are the most likely ways to modify the values of that field. Hope this helps to clarify the doubts you might still had.